# Door not flush to door stop at the top but is at the bottom

Tags: doors, interior, hinges

I have recently replaced an interior door and the door now bows away from the door stop at the top (latch side) about a 1/4 inch but is about flush at the bottom . I am at a loss for how to correct this. The hinges are mounted the same at the top and bottom and there is no significant gap issue in the door spacing from the frame. Any advice would be appreciated.

Added a photo of the corner in question. Hopefully it will help in describing what I am seeing. The hinge side is close to flush with the door stop, as is the bottom of the latch side.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Was it a pre-hung door? If one side of the frame is cut longer than the other (or if your floor isn't level and the frame rests on the ground) that could be pushing the frame out of shape.

Comment: Dave this should be posted as a comment, it is not an answer. I think he means the top of the stop on the side not the top of the jamb, meaning it is not askew in the height but that the  side of the jamb is twisted. Probably because the wall is not plumb and the jamb was set to the wall and not to plumb.

Comment: The door was not pre-hung but rather just a slab door placed in the existing frame. When mounted the door is close to the door stop in all areas except the top left (latch side), where it bows into the room about a 1/4". When adjusting the hinges, if I pull the bottom hinge out a quarter inch it pulls the top in to the stop but this too pulls the door away from the stop at the same hinge. I will look to see if the wall/jamb is plumb or not.

Comment: Alaska, sorry still new to this. I tried to leave a comment originally, but I guess I need to be more active before I can do that?